# Join three tables indirectly multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
1- j_order: order_id, order_created,
2- j_order_product: order_product_code, order_product_name, product_id, order_id
3- j_product_category: product_id, category_id
```

Now, I need to select all these fields.
The relations are:

```
j_order.order_id = j_order_product.order_id
j_order_product.product_id = j_product_category.product_id
```

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT  j_order.order_id, order_created , order_product_code, 
    order_product_name, j_order_product.product_id, j_product_category.category_id 
    FROM  `j_order` 
    INNER JOIN `j_order_product`
    ON j_order.order_id = j_order_product.order_id
    INNER JOIN `j_product_category`
    ON j_product_category.product_id = j_order_product.product_id
    WHERE category_id=2
```

Problem: This is returning only one product per order. So for orders with multiple products, only the first is visible.

Comment: i don't see a `product_id` column in `j_order_product` and this is being used in the `join` condition.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten. Pls see my edit.

Comment: Are you sure you've got orders with multiple products in category_id = 2?  Or do you want to return the *entire* order if *at least one* product in the order has category_id = 2?

Comment: @BaconBits yes, I've got orders with multiple products belonging to 2 different categories (including category 2) and I only want to display those products that belong to this category.

Comment: Well, your query syntax is not wrong.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps add sample data and/or a fiddle link to your question so we can see the underlying data you are working with.

Comment: Please show some data; and show what you're getting and what you expect. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  j_order.order_id, order_created , order_product_code, 
    order_product_name, j_order_product.product_id, j_product_category.category_id 
    FROM  `j_order` 
    INNER JOIN `j_order_product`
    ON j_order.order_id = j_order_product.order_id
    INNER JOIN `j_product_category`
    ON j_product_category.product_id = j_order_product.product_id
```

This will work fine.
I have excluded `WHERE category_id=2`, this is why it was showing only `one Product per Order`(**with category 2)**.

Hope this helps.